# Untrusted package apt-transport-https

Tags: debian, apt, https

I am using Debian wheezy and I would like to install the package `apt-transport-https`, which allows to access apt repositories through the `https` protocol.

What really puzzles me is that the `apt-get` gives me the following message:

```
$ sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apt-transport-https
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
Need to get 109 kB of archives.
After this operation, 166 kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  apt-transport-https
Install these packages without verification [y/N]?
```

I pressed `N` because I would like to clarify this before installing the package. Why is no authentication information for this package provided? I would expect this to be the default, especially for a package that provides a secure transfer protocol.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When running `apt-get update` for a `https` mirror without apt-transport-https installed, you probably invalidated your cached (sources) data, as a side effect invalidating the signatures - this should fix itself after running "apt-get update" again (you might have to revert to a non-https mirror temporarily).

Comment: I've added sury repo (https://packages.sury.org/php/), run `apt update`, after which I tried to install `apt-transport-https`. That gave me the warning. I disabled the repo (comment out, `apt update`), and the warning never appeared again.

Answer (score 1):

Debian adds keys that will be used to sign the packages in the future to the debian-archive-keyring package. That's why you need this package updated. If `apt-get update` won't work, you might have to (re)install keyrings:

`sudo apt-get remove debian-keyring debian-archive-keyring`

`sudo apt-get clean`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get -y install debian-keyring debian-archive-keyring`

Source: [server fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/337278/debian-how-can-i-securely-get-debian-archive-keyring-so-that-i-can-do-an-apt-g)